# Is this proof correct (lower bound on the permutation problem)?

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding a proof, the problem is one equality at the end of the proof which I don't understand.

The theorem which is being proven:
[image: Theoreom which is being proven]

At the end of the proof, the equality which I don't understand is marked in red with a question mark beside it.

Now look at the marked equality, the numerators are equal as shown at the beginning of the picture. Clearly, the denominators must be equal but I don't see how they can be equal?

What am I missing?

(note that I didn't include the beginning of the proof as I think it's not relevant to show the equality, correct me if I'm wrong)
[image: End of the proof]

**To summarize the question:**

Why does $log\left(\dfrac{n}{B} \cdot \binom{M}{B}\right) = 2B \cdot log\left(\dfrac{M}{B}\right)$?

Comment: We have $B\log\frac{eM}B=B\log\frac MB+B<2B\log\frac MB$ provided $M>eB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They're not equal, but in a way that doesn't make any difference.**

We've shown that because $\frac nB < \sqrt{\binom MB}$, we have
$$\log \left(\frac nB \cdot \binom MB^{1/2}\right) < 
\log \left(\binom MB^{1/2} \cdot \binom MB^{1/2}\right) =  \log \binom MB < 2B \log \frac MB.$$
In exactly the same way, we can show that
$$\log \left(\frac nB \cdot \binom MB\right) < \log \left(\binom MB^{1/2} \cdot \binom MB\right) = \frac32 \log \binom MB < 3B \log \frac{M}{B}.$$
So we can put a $3B \log \frac MB$ in the denominator instead of $2B \log \frac MB$, but since we're only interested in the asymptotic size of the answer anyway, those are equivalent for our purposes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to write $\geq$ instead of $=$ then?

Comment: The circled one next to the question mark might as well be a $=$, because there's a $\Omega$ in that statement, which implies an asymptotic lower bound anyway. (e.g. it's equally correct to write $n^3 \ge \Omega(n^2)$ and $n^3 = \Omega(n^2)$.)

Comment: So because of the $\Omega$ we can write whatever we want in the denominator (and numerator) as long as it makes the expression greater? Even if we add factors outside of the $\Omega$ like in this example? Is it legit to use such reasoning whenever we use landau notation?

Comment: I do think that there's a typo somewhere in the proof because, even if correct, the reason the statement holds isn't clear. But in general, $\frac{\Omega(f(n))}{g(n)}$ is the same as $\Omega(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)})$, so in this case it doesn't matter if the factors are on the inside or the outside - and a constant factor obviously doesn't affect the $\Omega$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the reason the statement holds isn't clear"?

Comment: I just mean that I had to write this answer explaining it for you so that it would make sense.